# How to check that SObject field is present in SOQL query

Tags: sobject, fields, record

When you try to attempt to the field that not present in SOQL query, you get error like that:

> System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.Account
>   AnonymousBlock: line 5, column 1

How I can to check that the field field is present in SOQL query?

Comment: field exist in object or added in soql ?

Comment: Field exist in the SOQL query

Comment: I can to serialize and desalinize the record, but it is very expensive.

Comment: Why do you need to check? Can't you just add all fields that you need to the SOQL query? Or is it dynamic in some way so that you can't predict which fields you'll need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a new method on sObject(as of Summer 16) for this:

```
getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap

See also:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm

Comment: I presume, getPopulatedFieldsAsMap can't be used for List<sObject> of records

Comment: Great!  I have one query for the grid, and one for the detail which includes an additional full-text field.  Sample code that worked for me: ```public LogDTO(ErrorLog__c log) {
      Map<String, Object> m = log.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

      this.id = log.Id;
      this.createdDate = log.CreatedDate;
      this.type = log.Type__c;
      this.status = log.StatusCode__c;
      this.relatedId = log.RelatedID__c;
      this.message = log.Message__c;

      if (m.keySet().contains('LogDescription__c')) {
        this.detail = log.LogDescription__c;
      }
    }```